# Can a Thunderbolt iMac use Target Display Mode on a Thunderbolt MacBook running Windows?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, bootcamp, thunderbolt

If I have:

- 2011 27" iMac (running OS X)
- 2012 15" MacBook Pro (running Windows 7 via Boot Camp)

and connect the MacBook to the iMac via a Thunderbolt cable, can the iMac use Target Display Mode to act as the display for the MacBook?

According to [Apple's FAQ](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US#17) this does not work if the *iMac* is running Windows but I cannot find a definite answer on if this works if the MacBook is running Windows.

Comment: My mid 2009 Macbook Pro running Windows 7 through bootcamp was able to use the mini-display port on the mid 2009 iMacs 27", neither had T-Bolt, but the drivers and everything worked fine when displaying it. Since they both have thunderbolt they should not have any issues since the bootcamp drivers are up to date. If you have the MacBook Pro, take it to an Apple Store and plug it into their iMacs and test it out. That's how I tested mine out before.

Comment: @de_an777 Aren't any Apple Stores in New Zealand or I would try this. Also, the way target display mode worked changed with the adoption of Thunderbolt. Thunderbolt ports can't (or won't) act as Minidisplay-input, only output. You could plug a HDMI-to-Minidisplay cable from a GPU into a 2010 iMac and put it in target display mode. You can't do that with a 2011 iMac; they only work with TBolt cables and both computers need to be TBolt-capable. This is why I'm worried if it will work or not.

Comment: Theories aside, it does not work for me (and I have tried for a while) and I have yet to hear of anyone who has done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this and can confirm it does not work. It works fine from OS X --> OS X but not if the MacBook is running Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It *should* work. The iMac is taking Thunderbolt input, so, assuming the MacBook is putting out a full Thunderbolt signal (which I assume the Thunderbolt chipset can't not do), it ought to work.

If it *doesn't* "just work", it could be a driver issue. Does Boot Camp come with Thunderbolt drivers for Windows?

Comment: Your question made me think of something I should have considered: if a T-Bolt Mac running Bootcamp works with a Thunderbolt Display and according to this, https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US#sysreq, yes it does. So there must be Windows Thunderbolt drivers for it, and that gives me a lot of hope that it should work with an iMac too.

Comment: @Glass Did you un-accept my answer? Any particular reason why?

Comment: Sorry, yes I did. I meant to update this weeks ago but I ended up testing some other solutions and it slipped my mind. I have since acquired a 2012 MBP and Target Display Mode on the iMac works fine when the MBP is running OS X but I have not been able to get it to work when it is running Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it? The Thunderbolt connection doesn't belong to the OS, just to the hardware.